# Cordova plugins failed to load

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, inappbrowser

I have a bug in cordova i tried to debug it  using android studio and i got failed to load resources,Iam not sure what is the problem exactly and what else to provide in order to help with the bug.

When i run the android studio i get :

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library[**tested_artifact**::CordovaLib]Mobile/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

[image: debuggin on android studio]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed : i uninstalled and reinstalled All the plugins. i think only couple of them caused the bug  not sure which plugin exactly .

Answer (score 0):

cordova android only supports a limited range of sdks as specified in:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

As per this page you can set these properties in one of four ways:

By setting environment variables like so:
  $ export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvMinSdkVersion=20
  $ cordova build android

By using the --gradleArg flag in your Cordova build or run commands:
  $ cordova run android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=20

By placing a file called gradle.properties in your Android platform folder (/platforms/android) and setting the properties in it like so:
  # In /platforms/android/app/gradle.properties
  cdvMinSdkVersion=20

By extending build.gradle via a build-extras.gradle file and setting the property like so:
  // In /platforms/android/app/build-extras.gradle
  ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = 20

Comment: Thank you, i found a solution by uninstalling/reinstalling the plugins, but thanks for the help.